# Can you shape a wand or rod like a gun?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

Can you shape a wand or rod like a pistol or rifle without unbalancing anything, like in this YouTube clip? “[[Knight's & Magic] The Gunlike Rod !!](https://youtu.be/STGJhT6-8f0?t=63)”

I know that in that anime a wand is used more as a focus than like a Pathfinder wand or rod. Nonetheless, would this shaping or modification of wands or rods break anything in the RAW? Does the shape of the wand or rod affect anything game mechanics wise?

I'm not thinking it would give any benefit, this is just purely for looks.

Comment: You actually ask two questions here. 1. Can a wand be this shape by rules as written? and 2. If you and your DM decides the wand is this shape, could it unbalance anything?

Comment: @enkryptor I think they're closely linked enough for it to be OK in this case

Comment: @Wibbs i think answers might differ. No, a wand cannot be gun-shaped RAW, *but* it doesn't affect the game mechanics.

Answer (score 7):

Per RAW,

> A wand is a thin baton that contains a single spell of 4th level or lower.
>
> A wand is 6 to 12 inches long, 1/4 inch thick, and weighs no more than 1 ounce. Most wands are wood, but some are bone, metal, or even crystal.

**So no, unfortunately, a wand could not be shaped like a gun.** Even a basic gun shape would be more than 1/4 in thick and probably more than an ounce.

That being said, GM Fiat is a thing and if you're not asking for any benefit (ie easier 'draw', skill bonuses, resistance to disarm/steal, etc), then no GM I've played with would say no.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69269/discussion-on-answer-by-ifusaso-can-you-shape-a-wand-or-rod-like-a-gun).

Answer (score 5):

**No,** the rules dictate how a wand looks like: 6 to 12 inch by 1/4th inch diameter and 1 ounce of weight.

However, such a stick could be mounted on a wood holder that does look like a pistol body, yet nothing in the rules says anything if this would allow to use the wand.

It would be the GM's decision if such a holder changes anything, but if it is just for fluff *I* would not change something - at least as long as it does just holds a single wand/rod.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Remember, *one* question per question page. The issue of whether it would count as a weapon was removed from the question already and shouldn't re-appear on this page. (Also, comments aren't for discussion.) If you have a new question, please post it as a new question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69268/discussion-on-answer-by-trish-can-you-shape-a-wand-or-rod-like-a-gun).